# Primary Keys and User Interfaces

Tags: sql, user-interface, primary-key

I'm writing an application that reads data from a relational database, let's the user change the data, and writes it back.

I am unsure how to deal with the primary keys since I do not want to show them in the user interface output. What are good practices to hold the primary keys invisible for the user but so that they can easily be retrieved after the changes in the gui are made?

I use C#, Windows Forms and sqlite, if needed.

**EDIT: Example: I have a text input that contains the wage of a employee. Can I save the the primary key of that employee bound to that text input, so that changes made by the user can be written back easily?**

Comment: You can have invisible label or textbox on your form. And set primary key value to that control. Make control visible false.

Comment: It depends e.g. if the entities in question were the elements of the periodic table then it would surely be practically impossible not to show one or more candidate keys in the UI?

Comment: Thanks for the tip with control invisible!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an ORM you have the PK as a property of the object. If you're using SQL queries directly you can hold PK in an internal variable in your form class.

Comment: But I might get a problem if the user interface shows 10 data rows and I need to save all 10 primary keys in internal variables, right? But I see, I will think about using an array

Comment: I would use a collection of objects where every object has one property for each column data. Basically a ORM does this way: when you get a row create a new object or you create an object and then saves to database. One row mapped to an object and edited in your form where you can show or hide any property as you wish.